# return value in android button

Tags: java, android

I want to return the imageUrls array for this part of code
"**adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, imageUrls);**" when the button click
its error say you cannot return value in void method, i dont know to use what method to return the value,

my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
public static String res="";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String[] imageUrls = new String[0];
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, imageUrls);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new server_side("http://192.168.1.6:81/upload/time.php","").execute();
        String imageUrls[]={"http://localhost:81/upload/url.jpg"};

        if (!res.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "get data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
return imageUrls;
}
});

}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont forget you are inside of an **overriden** method... the
`public void onClick(View v)`  method of the **View.OnClickListener** interface...

So basically you ***JUST CAN NOT*** return anything there... the most you can do is call return,

## The solution to that:

you can for sure modify the logic

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView list;
private LazyAdapter adapter;
private String res = "";
//here declare as class variable....
private String[] imageUrls;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //here initialize it....
    imageUrls = new String[1];
    
    Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, imageUrls);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new server_side("http://192.168.1.6:81/upload/time.php","").execute();
            //here asign it some value....
            imageUrls[0] = {"http://localhost:81/upload/url.jpg"};
            if (!res.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "get data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: use the global String array you defined for the class instead of declaring a new one in the method...

Comment: i define the imageurls in button method but until show me the error

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
        new server_side("http://192.168.1.6:81/upload/time.php","").execute();
        String[] imageUrls = new String[0];
        imageUrls[] = {"http://localhost:81/upload/url.jpg"};

        if (!res.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "get data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

Comment: do it backwards... all variables you declare there are gone after the method exits...

Comment: can your help me more because im beginner programmer in android.

Comment: if i want to set the data from new server_side("http://192.168.1.6:81/upload/time.php"); to imageUrls[0] , what should i do?

Comment: use a variable instead of hard coding the server address :)